# $.post does not submit data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, post

```
$("#contact-us-form").submit(function () {

    var nameVal = $("input[name=name]").val();
    var companyVal = $("input[name=company]").val();
    var titleVal = $("input[name=title]").val();
    var emailVal = $("input[name=email]").val();
    var phoneVal = $("input[name=phone]").val();
    var messageVal = $("input[name=message]").val();

    alert(nameVal);
    alert(emailVal);

    $.post("/mailer.php", {
        name: nameVal,
        company: companyVal,
        title: titleVal,
        email: emailVal,
        phone: phoneVal,
        message: messageVal
    }, function (data) {
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        $('#thanks').show();
    });
});
```

mailer.php in in root, and it contains:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $to = "myemail@domain.com";
    $subject = "Inquiry";
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $company = $_POST['company'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $body = <<<HEREDOC
        From: $name
        Company: $company
        Title: $title 
        E-Mail: $email
        Phone: $phone \n
        Message: $message 
HEREDOC;

    mail($to, $subject, $body);

}

?>
```

I see the `name` and `email` alerts with correct data, but the data alert is empty, just shows `Data Loaded:`, so I'm guessing that the data is not submitted correctly.

How do I fix it?

Many thanks!

Comment: when you post using jQuery, the value of DATA will be what's returned from your server-side handler, mailer.php. What does it return? did you set a breakpoint in it to see what you're getting posted to it? is it returning anything? are you using Firebug/Web Inspector to see what the request/response look like?

Comment: Maybe your PHP script has an error?

Comment: You can install the Firefox "TamperData" plugin to see what's going from the browser and back from your server.

Comment: included mailer.php in the description.

Comment: so the php script doesn't produce any any actual output, no print $body or any value for the javascript to consume ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added `return false;` and it worked! :)

Comment: `return false;` at the end of `submit` or `event.preventDefault();` anywhere in `submit` will stop the page from changing / refreshing on submittal. So your page was changing before the JS had a chance to do its work.

Answer (score 1):

The 'data' callback is what the form you're posting to responds with. So, its contents depend on what mailer.php is supposed to respond with.

---

EDIT:
There's no 'echo/print' in mailer.php, so there's no way for you to know if the mailing succeeded. Besides the fact that you're not sanitizing the content, or checking for a valid email address, you should echo a basic successs or true or false message at the end, so you can tell your JavaScript what to do.

So, something like

```
$result = mail($to, $subject, $body);
if($result)
echo 'success';
```

Then, in your js callback

```
if(data=="success")
{
$('#thanks').show();
}
else{
$('#error').show();
```

---

EDIT #2: Does the Submit input element actually have the name 'submit'? It's possible you're just failing that `isset()` check every time.

Comment: included mailer.php in the description.

Comment: @Nimbuz - It looks like mailer isn't sending any info back (it has no output), since it just sends an email.

Comment: added echos to mailer.php, still nothing. :(

Comment: @Nimbuz see my final edit. Is it possible you're just not actually sending a POST field named 'submit'?

Comment: Hmm...no its `<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn-send">Send Message</button>` The form tag is `<form method="post" action="" id="contact-us-form" class="cl">`

Comment: Running out of ideas. Are you sure php mail is enabled on your server?

Comment: Yep, the form worked before I tried using $.post to submit. Previously, I was just redirecting to mailer.php for processing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `mailer.php` isn't responding with anything. It looks like it's sending an email, so that's why `data` is empty. The fact that the `post` callback does fire shows that the data was sent to `mailer.php`.

You can use the second argument of the callback to check:

```
, function (data, textStatus) {
        alert("Data Loaded: " + textStatus);
        $('#thanks').show();
```

or the exact same thing using the `arguments` array:

```
, function () {
        alert("Data Loaded: " + arguments[1]);
        $('#thanks').show();
```

If you want `data` to actually contain something, then you can output the `subject` in `mailer.php` like:

```
...
echo $subject;
mail($to, $subject, $body);
```

Now `alert(data)` should work.

---

Also, be sure to prevent the default submit of the form, so the page doesn't change while this is happening:

```
$("#contact-us-form").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
```

Comment: What is the `textStatus`? Does it say `success`?